# Serve static file without file extension in ASP.net

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, http-status-code-404

I want to imitate a REST-Server (for testing purposes) and therefore want to make some static text files available at certain URLs on localhost.

When I try to just put those files in a Visual Studio folder, that is available via HTTP, then I get an error 404.17, saying that the file seems to be a script.

How can I tell my Visual Studio / IIS, that this file should not be executed, but be served 1:1 to the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure the file's extension is included in the "Mime types" list of the containing site.

Comment: Actually my file does not have a file extension. Is there a mime mapping for "no extension"? And where do I find the "Mime types" list of the site? Is it somewhere in the settings?

Comment: @slartidan oops... and you said exactly that :-(. You can set a mime mapping for extensionless files, but unless you have a dedicated site in IIS it could well interfere with other things. You might be better off with a little HTTP handler – just enough code to wrap `HttpResponse.WriteFile` with setting the right content type header.